# Combinatorial Algebra with Variables

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is ${m+1} \choose {m-1}$. The answer is $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. I am stuck on solving this algebraically. If someone could tell me where the two comes from I would be helped, because I know how to get to m(m+1) just not two as the divisor.

Comment: Show us how you get the $m(m+1)$, and maybe we can figure out how you are missing the 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

According to the definition of $n \choose m$, it $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$

So let's take your "choose" and apply the formula:

${m+1 \choose m-1} = \frac{(m+1)!}{(m-1)!2!}$ = $\frac{(m+1)(m)(m-1)!}{2(m-1)!}$ = $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$

Here it is...

Comment: I understand (m+1)! and (m-1)! but not 2!   Where did the 2! come from?

Comment: Just use the formula: $(m+1-(m-1))!$ = $(m+1-m+1)!$ = $2!$

Comment: is it clearer @Jinzu?

Comment: Yes that helps I can solve it now, thanks. How to put the n choose m in parentheses? Also how to put a line for division instead of '/'?

Comment: Yes there's a document about the math language here. it's somewhere in the "help" section. I've done a little search for you but I couldn't find...sorry. specifically for fractions, just write \frac{}{} and between the first {} put the expression for the top part and in the second {} the expression for the bottom part. the total \frac expression should be surrounded by $

Comment: I will look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this property:

$$^aC_b=^aC_{a-b}$$
Hence:
$$^{m+1}C_{m-1}=^{m+1}C_{2}={{(m+1)m}\over 2}$$

Comment: this is the formula yes indeed. However I was helped more by the more specific instead of the general. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use theorem of symmetrie $$\binom{m}{k}=\binom{m}{m-k}$$ and
$$\binom{m}{k}=\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-k+1)}{k!}$$ to get
$$\binom{m+1}{m-1}=\binom{m+1}{(m+1)-(m-1}=\binom{m+1}{2}=\frac{(m+1)m}{2!}=\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$$